# GTLService not executing query

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I have a GTLServiceTicket object aimed to facilitate me to upload files. It is defined earlier in my code as

```
GTLServiceTicket *_uploadFileTicket;
```

And called using

```
    NSString *mimeType = [self MIMETypeForFilename:filename
                                   defaultMIMEType:@"video/mp4"];
    GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters =
    [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithFileHandle:fileHandle
                                               MIMEType:mimeType];
    uploadParameters.uploadLocationURL = locationURL;

    GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForVideosInsertWithObject:video
                                                                        part:@"snippet,status"
                                                            uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

    GTLServiceYouTube *service = self.youTubeService;

    _uploadFileTicket = [service executeQuery:query
                            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                GTLYouTubeVideo *uploadedVideo,
                                                NSError *error) {

                                // Callback
                                NSLog(@"Here!");
                                //Other uploading file stuff
```

This *used* to be working really well. Now the "Here" doesnt even get called. So whatever is happening, its not running that GTLServiceTicket object at all. Its only until very recently that its stopped working. Within that time frame I've implemented two new features:

- Google plus sign in
- Youtube video searches and gets (on a different view controller).

And heres what I can confirm about my problem:

- No error is passed at all, I have an if statement to catch any errors and I cant even get that. Its like its a dud command.

  - The file location/URL are **correct**

So my questions are:

- How would I go about further investigating this? As in, where would I look within the frameworks to find out where it is going wrong? What trail is this command following (I have NO idea and have tried to find it).
- Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: That's really strange. I don't have any ideas off the top of my head. In the past, what I've done is go backwards in my source control until I find what changelist diff introduced the error. Can you do this? If you are using git, git bisect helps a lot here.

Comment: The solution was actually really simple. I had moved some files around prior to including my g+ sign in, and for some reason got rid of GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.m - large headache for a stupid error!

Comment: Ah, good to hear you solved it. Yeah, sometimes I wish Xcode would complain more, and earlier!